# Bare-metal hello world PPC64 (QEMU + OFW) not working

Tags: powerpc, bare-metal

I'm new to bare-metal and kernel programming, and what better way to start my journey than with a hello world!

Sadly, when it comes to my architecture of choice, PPC64 (Using QEMU and OpenFirmware), I struggle to find relevant information or code examples on how to make a hello world program, using the firmware.

So far I've struggled to get the most simple things working, so far I've tried using this `start` as my main function and this linker script:

```
.section .boot, "aw"
.global start

start:
    b start # Basically halt the machine.
```

```
ENTRY(start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 1M;

    .text : {
        *(.boot)
        *(.text*)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data*)
        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

I've tested it with:

```sh
clang --target=ppc64-unknown-elf -c <asm_file> -o <asm_file>.o
ld.lld --oformat elf_ppc64 --nostdlib -T <linkscript> <asm_file>.o -o output.elf
qemu-system-ppc64 -kernel output.elf -serial stdio
```

But so far the only outcome of my attempts has been this output of SLOF in QEMU emulation:

```
Detected RAM kernel at 400000 (4 bytes) 

  Welcome to Open Firmware

  Copyright (c) 2004, 2017 IBM Corporation All rights reserved.
  This program and the accompanying materials are made available
  under the terms of the BSD License available at
  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php

Booting from memory...


( 700 ) Program Exception [ 1dbf04c4 ]


    R0 .. R7           R8 .. R15         R16 .. R23         R24 .. R31
8000000000002000   000000001e478200   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   
000000001dc71000   8000000000000000   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   
0000000000000000   000000001e477010   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   
0000000000000000   0000000000000030   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   
0000000000000000   000000000000005b   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   
000000001dbf04c4   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   
0000000000000000   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   
0000000000000000   0000000000000000   0000000000000000   0000000000000000
```

How could I get this little snippet to work? Is there any documentation I could use to finish the complete hello world program? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the micropython powerpc port README here:
  https://github.com/micropython/micropython/tree/master/ports/powerpc

It shows you how to run qemu and skip open firmware directly into your test program. You'll want a stripped binary rather than the elf (see the objcopy in the Makefile)

In that directory there is a linker script and a head.S which shows you the basics.

Good luck!